# Reply to a blog comment using modal in laravel

Tags: bootstrap-4, laravel-5.7

I already set the comments and replies apparently why I'm trying to comment it goes on the first comment.. so all replies goes to the first comment. I have the input hidden field on the modal.

The problem is in the modal where the $comment->id changes from 11 to 13 when I click the button and open the modal.. Here is the actual https://i.stack.imgur.com/gemzp.jpg

blade.php

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
            <div class="comment-wrap">
               <div class="photo">
                  <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('/images/frontend_images/uploads/{{$comment->user->avatar}}')"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="comment-block">
                  <p class="comment-text">{{$comment->body}}
                  </p>
                  <div class="bottom-comment">
                     <div class="comment-date"><a href="{{route('profile_posts_path',$comment->user_id)}}">{{$comment->user->username}}</a> on {{$comment->created_at->format('l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A')}}</div>
                     <ul class="comment-actions">
                        <li class="complain">{{$comment->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</li>
                        <li class="reply"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-mini" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reply" >Reply {{$comment->id}} 
                           </button>
                        </li>
 <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="reply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                           <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                 <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reply to a Comment</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('reply.add') }}">
                                       @csrf
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                          <textarea name="comment_body" id="comment_body" cols="60" rows="3" placeholder="Type your comment here...."></textarea>
                                          <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="{{ $blog->id }}" />
                                          <input type="text" name="comment_id" value="{{$comment->id}}" />
                                       </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                 </form>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            </div>
            @if($comment->replies)
            @foreach($comment->replies as $rep)
            <div class="comment-wrap" style="margin-left:50px;width:710px;">
               <div class="photo">
                  <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('/images/frontend_images/uploads/{{$rep->user->avatar}}')"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="comment-block">
                  <p class="comment-text">{{$rep->body}}
                  </p>
                  <div class="bottom-comment">
                     <div class="comment-date"><a href="{{route('profile_posts_path',$rep->user_id)}}">{{$rep->user->username}}</a> on {{$rep->created_at->format('l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A')}}</div>
                     <ul class="comment-actions">
                        <li class="complain">{{$rep->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            @endif
            @endforeach

I want the reply on the particular comment..
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a modal for each comment which I think not needed. one is enough, but even if you want keep them they should have unique ids, if give them "the same id dom will get first element has the id" I think its better to pass comment id to the modal and only make one.

```
   @foreach($comments as $comment)
      <div class="comment-wrap">
         <div class="photo">
            <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('/images/frontend_images/uploads/{{$comment->user->avatar}}')"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="comment-block">
            <p class="comment-text">{{$comment->body}}</p>
            <div class="bottom-comment">
               <div class="comment-date">
                  <a href="{{route('profile_posts_path',$comment->user_id)}}">
                     {{$comment->user->username}}
                  </a> on {{$comment->created_at->format('l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A')}}
               </div>
               <ul class="comment-actions">
                  <li class="complain">{{$comment->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</li>
                  <li class="reply">
                     <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                     <button type="button" class="reply-modal btn btn-outline-primary btn-mini" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reply" >Reply {{$comment->id}} 
                     </button>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      @if($comment->replies)
         @foreach($comment->replies as $rep)
            <div class="comment-wrap" style="margin-left:50px;width:710px;">
               <div class="photo">
                  <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('/images/frontend_images/uploads/{{$rep->user->avatar}}')"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="comment-block">
                  <p class="comment-text">{{$rep->body}}</p>
                  <div class="bottom-comment">
                     <div class="comment-date">
                        <a href="{{route('profile_posts_path',$rep->user_id)}}">{{$rep->user->username}}</a> on {{$rep->created_at->format('l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A')}}
                     </div>
                     <ul class="comment-actions">
                        <li class="complain">{{$rep->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         @endforeach
      @endif
   @endforeach

   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="reply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="replyModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
         <form method="post" action="{{ route('reply.add') }}">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title" id="replyModal">Reply to a Comment</h5>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                  @csrf
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <textarea name="comment_body" id="comment_body" cols="60" rows="3" placeholder="Type your comment here...."></textarea>
                     <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="{{ $blog->id }}" />
                     <input id="comment_id" type="text" name="comment_id" value="" />
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
         </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

then you can pass comment Id by a simple jquery script:

```
$(document).on("click", ".reply-modal", function () {
     var commentId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal #reply #comment_id").val( commentId );
     // it is unnecessary to have to manually call the modal.
     // $('#reply').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: i will try this one.. or is it ok to put the comment->id also in the id="reply{{$comment->id}}"

Comment: I guess It will work if you generate unique ID for each modal and also use the ID for its button `data-target`